# Why is this rule preventing my GitLab stage from running?

Tags: gitlab-ci

In my .gitlab-ci.yml file I have this stage, which uses environment variables in artifacts from a previous stage:

```
build_dev_containers:
  stage: build_dev_containers  
  variables:
    CI_DEBUG_TRACE: "true"
  script:
    - whoami
```

…and it outputs the following debug information:

> ++ DEV_CONTAINERS=true

If I change it by adding the following rule, the stage no longer runs:

```
  rules:
    - if: '$DEV_CONTAINERS == "true"'
```

Any idea what I could be doing wrong?

Not sure if this information adds any value, but just in case:

My previous stage outputs a .env file in its artifacts, and it contains the value

> DEV_CONTAINERS=true

Here is the complete file.  The powershell script creates package.env in the root path:

```
image: microsoft/dotnet:latest

variables:
  GIT_RUNNER_PATH: 'C:\GitLab'
  SCRIPTS_PATH: '.\Lava-Tools\BuildAndDeploy\BuildServer'

stages:
  - dev_deploy
  - build_dev_containers

dev_deploy:
  stage: dev_deploy
  tags:
    - lava
  variables:
    GIT_CLONE_PATH: '$GIT_RUNNER_PATH/builds/d/$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA/$CI_PROJECT_NAME'
  script:
    - 'powershell -noprofile -noninteractive -executionpolicy Bypass -command ${SCRIPTS_PATH}\createdevdeployvars.ps1 -Branch "${CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME}" -ShortCommitHash "${CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA}"'
  artifacts:
    reports:
      dotenv: package.env

build_dev_containers:
  stage: build_dev_containers  
  image: docker.repo.ihsmarkit.com/octo/alpine/build/dotnet:latest
  tags:
    - lava-linux-containers
  variables:
    CI_DEBUG_TRACE: "true"
  script:
    - whoami
  rules:
    - if: '$DEV_CONTAINERS == "true"'
```

Comment: is DEV_CONTAINERS defined inside image? If so then it could be reason because my understanding is rules are evaluated before image is instantiated

Comment: Are loading the .env file in the same job as de condition?

Comment: I've included the complete file in my question.  I'm not explicitly loading the .env file, but the environment variable is displayed when using CI_DEBUG_TRACE: "true", so I assume I don't need to explicitly load the file.

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov, perhaps I should use an if statement in script:, rather than in rules:.

Comment: @StephenOberauer I'm pretty sure rules are evaluated before image is instantiated so `DEV_CONTAINERS` is not visible to rules because it **will be** defined as part of image instantiation later.

Comment: Moreover, I'm 99.999% sure rules are evaluated before very first image is instantiated so there is no way to achieve what you are trying to, using rules

Answer (score 0):

The rules are evaluated before the jobs begin, so a rule cannot evaluate the output from a job.

As a workaround I used `if` statements in my *script:* section:

```
build_dev_containers:
  stage: build_dev_containers  
  image: docker.repo.ihsmarkit.com/octo/alpine/build/dotnet:latest
  tags:
    - lava-linux-containers
  script:
    - if [ "$DEV_CONTAINERS" == "true" ]; then echo "DEV_CONTAINERS is true - running"; else echo "DEV_CONTAINERS is not true - skipping"; exit 0; fi
    - whoami

deploy_dev_containers:
  stage: deploy_dev_containers
  tags:
    - lava
  script:
    - |
      if ( "$DEV_CONTAINERS" -eq "true" ) {
        Write-Output "DEV_CONTAINERS is true - running"
      }
      else {
        Write-Output "DEV_CONTAINERS is not true - skipping"
        exit 0
      }
    - ls
```